# Why Git fail to connect to local repository with Jenkins (bad config file)?

Tags: git, jenkins

When I gave the local repository path in Git under the Jenkins, I am getting the error message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : 
Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h E:/New folder (2) HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: bad config file line 1 in C:/\Users\usr1/.gitconfig
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure what `%HOME%` (which isn't defined by default) refers to (before launching Jenkins):

`C:/\Users\usr1` might not be an accessible path, while `C:\Users\usr1` might.

As mention in this [blog post](http://dustint.com/post/299/hudson-jenkins-and-git-http-authentication):

> Create a new Execute Shell build step. Execute the command:

```
echo $HOME
```

> Run the build and examine the output to see where `$HOME` is located