# configure git repository in jenkins

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins

I'm trying to configure the repository:
https://github.com/javpaw/game-of-life

into a job in jenkins using git plugin, but when I put the address of the repository:
git@github.com:javpaw/game-of-life.git

Source Code Management -> git -> repository Url I got this error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h
>   git@github.com:javpaw/game-of-life.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: stderr: No protocol specified No protocol specified
>
> (ssh-askpass:18881): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0 Host
>   key verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I found this question here in github: [Why Git fail to connect to local repository with Jenkins (bad config file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490981/why-git-fail-to-connect-to-local-repository-with-jenkins-bad-config-file)

but was not useful because I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

How can I solve this issue?

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a complete url, with https rather than ssh:

```
https://github.com/javpaw/game-of-life
```

You can also try the read-only address:

```
git://github.com/javpaw/game-of-life.git
```

But in both case, the important part is that you specify the protocol (`https://` or `git://`)

Comment: Thank you;Your reputation precedes you =)